# Basic bash scripting, enumeration and comman replacement tool issues

Tags: bash, debian

i am trying to generate many invalid ipv4 addresses and a few valid ones in my debian7 bash.
my plan was to go with:

```
echo {0..3 , 00..03 , 000..003 , 300..303 , 254..257 ,  0254..0257 , fail , 888}
echo -e "\n"!^.!^.!^.!^ >> ip.txt
```

but it just echoes

```
"{0..3 00..03 000..003 300..303 254..257 0254..0257 fail 888}" x4
```

whenever i give more than one area of number per curly bracket.

```
echo {a..c , A..C} end up as
"{a..c A..C}" 

where i want 

"a b c A B C"
```

so i am curious if this is even possible with >>only one curly bracket<<

__

My next thought was to solve it like this:

```
echo -e "\n"{0..3}.{0..3}.{0..3}.{0..3} >> ip.txt
^0..3^00..03

but there is only replaces one piece

echo -e "\n"{00..03}.{0..3}.{0..3}.{0..3} >> ip.txt
```

is there a way to use this "^x^y" tool to replace all at once?

sorry for this basic questions i just got into bash and want to learn at home too besides the school lessons

thankyou for any help or hints to necessary literature

Comment: Should the output look like this: `0 1 2 3 00 01 02 03 000 001 002 003 300 301 302 303 254 255 256 257 0254 0255 0256 0257 fail 888` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want somthing like this:

```
for a in {{0..3},{00..03},{000..003},{300..303},{254..257},{0254..0257},fail,888} ; do
    for b in {{0..3},{00..03},{000..003},{300..303},{254..257},{0254..0257},fail,888} ; do
        for c in {{0..3},{00..03},{000..003},{300..303},{254..257},{0254..0257},fail,888} ; do
            for d in {{0..3},{00..03},{000..003},{300..303},{254..257},{0254..0257},fail,888} ; do
                echo "$a"."$b"."$c"."$d"
            done
        done
    done
done
```

The script outputs `456976` wannabe IP addresses:

```
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.1
0.0.0.2
0.0.0.3
0.0.0.00

...

888.888.888.0255
888.888.888.0256
888.888.888.0257
888.888.888.fail
888.888.888.888
```

If you want to avoid using a loop you can concat each part by a `.` like this:

```
echo -e {{1..3},{5..7}}.{{1..3},{5..7}}.{{1..3},{5..7}}.{{1..3},{5..7}}"\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I tried to avoid the for. But you helped me find out what i tried to understand: {{a..c},{A..C}} THANKYOU :) Any idea how to replace all x's with y's when using ^x^y instead of only one?

Comment: Sure you can do that, simple concat them with a . instead of the loops.

Comment: Thanks again. I cannot upvote yet but i would ! maybe some day i have the reputation and come back here to upvote you :) <3

Comment: Nice to see that it works for you. Btw, you can click the accept button left beside the answer, this marks the answer as accepted.